# How can I watch for flashing command prompt windows?

Tags: windows, command-line

I would like to identify instances of flashing command prompt windows while using my computer running Windows 10. I know this could be due to a number of reasons, many of them innocuous but I would like to rule out any nefarious processes. Can there possibly be a log of completed cmd window processes or other ways of monitoring exactly what transpires?

Comment: I have the same issue on one of mu w11 pc's

Comment: Please don't put additional info, answers to questions, clarifications etc. to comments. Instead [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1770188/edit) your question. That way everything relevant is readily available, and the question itself gets more focused.

Answer (score 1):

Download [Sysinternals ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) from Microsoft and set it to monitor process create events. (You'll probably want to enable "Drop filtered events" in the menu, in order to reduce resource usage.)

Note that console windows are **not** guaranteed to be Cmd.exe or "Command Prompt" windows – a console window is automatically shown for any .exe that has the "console application" flag set during compile.